# Return the max Date

Tags: c#

```cs
[Column, Nullable] public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
[Association(QueryExpressionMethod = nameof(GetfffModified), CanBeNull = true)] 
public DateTime? xxxModified { get; set; } 
public static Expression<Func<Offer, IDataContext, IQueryable<DateTime?>>> GetfffModified()
{
    return (obj, db) => db.GetTable<OfferProducts>()
       .Where(rel => rel.OfferId == obj.OfferId)
       .OrderByDescending(i => i.ModifiedDate)
       .Select(x => x.ModifiedDate)
       .Take(1);
}

// here I am trying to set max date between ModifiedDate and xxxModified
public DateTime? Modified { get { return ModifiedDate; } set { ModifiedDate = value; } }
```

In above method I am trying to set the max date between ModifiedDate and xxxModified for Modified values .
Is there any possible  to do like that ?

Comment: I've edit your post to indicate that this *isn't* runnable Javascript. Could I request that you perform another edit to make it actually readable, ideally without horizontal scrolling? Use the preview to get the post into a state that you'd want to read it if you were trying to answer.

Comment: @tesrer, the great Jon Skeet commenting on your question.  Feel privileged.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

private DateTime? _FinalDate;

```
    public DateTime? FinalDate
    {
        get
        {
            if (ModifiedDate < OfferProductsModified)
            {
                return OfferProductsModified;
            }
            else
            {
                return ModifiedDate;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (ModifiedDate < OfferProductsModified)
            {
                _FinalDate = value;
            }
            else
            {
                //DEFAULT Value. 
                _FinalDate = ModifiedDate;
            }
        }
    }
```

I found a way